# NSDictionary Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to store data in the following fashion with a string as the key and I would like an array as the value.

key              objects

"letters"        {'a','b','c','d'}
"numbers"        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

Is this possible with `NSDictionary` in code? If so how would that look like? I'm really confused on this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A simple way to do this in code (and just one of many several ways you could do it):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", nil] forKey:@"letters"];
[dict setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], nil] forKey:@"numbers"];
```

That creates an `NSDictionary` with an array of strings and an array of `NSNumber` objects, there are other ways to create arrays, but that demonstrates a basic way to do it.

Per the comments below:

If you wanted to add items to the arrays one at a time...

```
  // create the dictionary and add the letters and numbers mutable arrays
  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  NSMutableArray *letters = [NSMutableArray array];
  NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
  [dict setObject:letters forKey:@"letters"];
  [dict setObject:numbers forKey:@"numbers"];

  // add a letter and add a number
  [[dict objectForKey:@"letters"] addObject:@"a"];
  [[dict objectForKey:@"numbers"] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];  
  // This now has an NSDictionary (hash) with two arrays, one of letters and one 
  // of numbers with the letter 'a' in the letters array and the number 1 in 
  // the numbers array
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this dynamically so that I add one key/value pair at a time  in code?

Comment: Doing:
[dict setObject:anObject forKey:@"key"];
is adding a key/value pair to the dictionary.

Comment: Yes you can but that's what the example is doing. In your question the key is "letters" and values is array of characters "a b c d". Isn't this what you are after?

Comment: I think he's wanting to be able to do something like `[dict appendObject: @"d" forKey:letters]`, where letters previously contained `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Comment: I added a second example that shows adding items one at a time

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have an `NSArray` called `letters` and one called `numbers` containing the correct values:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    letters, @"letters",
    numbers, @"numbers",
    nil
];
```

Make sure to `retain` if you want to keep `dict` around, or alternatively use `alloc` and `initWithObjectsAndKeys`.

See [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-SW10) API reference for more details.

Comment: you switched the order of the objects and keys

Comment: thank you for pointing that out to me :-) That still seems backwards to me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can represent them as property-lists.  [Property-List Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html).

```
<dict>
    <key>letters</key>
    <array>
        <string>a</string>
        <string>b</string>
        <string>c</string>
        <string>d</string>
    </array>
    <key>letters</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <integer>3</integer>
        <integer>4</integer>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <integer>6</integer>
        <integer>7</integer>
    </array>
 </dict>
```

For an overview of how to serialize and de-serialize your data in Cocoa, see [Archives and Serialization Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/index.html)