# How To Populate Array Via Text Input?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I populate an empty but initialized array via text input?

I want the + button in the navbar to bring up a UIAlert prompting for a text.  This text will then be stored in the array.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u can save that text in the nsstring.

but if u want to save the text in nsarry then u can do this

```
 NSArray *data= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textField.text,nil];
```

and in order to save data in already declared nsarry then u can do this. if ur array is @property and syntesized

```
NSArray *data= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textField.text,nil];
 self.urArray=data;
 [data release];
```

Comment: I actually think I may need to store it in a dictionary.  The plist needs to be an array of dictionarys I think.

Comment: check that link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908742/nsdictionary-objective-c

Comment: thanks Iqbal.  the problem is not populating the array, because I know how to do that, but it is how to populate using the text from a prompt that the user has to type in

Comment: Thanks iqbal.  One last question though.  I got the prompt working when I put the code in my ViewDidLoad.  But how can I assign it to alert when I click the + button in my navbar?  right now the + button is set to nil for the @selector.

Comment: how  u r creating the + button. if in interface builder then simply declare a function in header and implementaion class and then link it.

Comment: actually im using this code in my viewDidLoad:     `[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];`

Comment: if u r creating the button manually then u can do that like that    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"", @"") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(save_Clicked:)];

Comment: UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];

    [addButton release];

Comment: that is my full code in (void)viewDidLoad for the uiview holding the table

Comment: [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPrompt:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Ok, im getting unrecognized selector sent to instance error for showPrompt.  Do I need to name the method containing the UIAlertView "showPrompt"?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

Comment: for some reason it is not working, when i click the button it just freezes up

Comment: UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt:)];

Answer (score 1):

For initialize:

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

for populating:

```
[array addObject:textfied.text];
```